# Null values on reading custom JAD attributes

Tags: java, jsp, blackberry

I have a blackberry Application. It is downloaded from a web page which provides dynamic JAD file content. The JSP prints those :

```
out.println("Appid: " + appid);
out.println("Ip: " + user.getIp());
out.println("Servicename: " + service);
out.println("MIDlet-Version: 1.0.0");
out.println("MIDlet-Jar-URL: MyApp.jar");
out.println("MIDlet-Jar-Size: 91633");
out.println("MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0");
     (and other attributes goes on like that..)
```

I need to get my custom attributes like "Appid" but it **sometimes** gets null values. User can download and run the app, but some of them cannot get my custom attributes. I dont know it is about the phone model or the current state of OS, but according to my logs, this problem appears mostly on those devices :

9800 with OS 6.0.0.546

9300 with OS 6.0.0.570

9300 with OS 6.0.0.668

9320 with OS 7.1.0.398

My code to get attributes :

```
    CodeModuleGroup cmg = null;
    CodeModuleGroup[] allGroups = CodeModuleGroupManager.loadAll();
    String moduleName = ApplicationDescriptor
            .currentApplicationDescriptor().getModuleName();

    for (int i = 0; i < allGroups.length; i++) {
        if (allGroups[i].containsModule(moduleName)) {
            cmg = allGroups[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (cmg != null) {

        AppData.firstPageURL = cmg.getProperty("Firstpage");

        AppData.appId = cmg.getProperty("Appid");
        AppData.firstIp = cmg.getProperty("Ip");
        AppData.firstSubServiceName = cmg.getProperty("Servicename");

        for (Enumeration e = cmg.getPropertyNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {

            String name = (String) e.nextElement();
            String value = cmg.getProperty(name);
            AppData.errorStep += "-" + name + ":" + value + "-";
        }
    }
```

By the way, I determined that the code in the for loop above never runs in these cases.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, `ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor().getModuleName()` gives the name of the sibling cod file instead of the main cod file. So, if your module name is `MyApp`, the function may return `MyApp-1`.

To solve this, you have to strip out the number after the hyphen.

```
String moduleName = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor()
         .getModuleName();
if(moduleName.indexOf('-') > 0) {
    moduleName = moduleName.substring(0, moduleName.indexOf('-');
}
```

Comment: I still see the same result. I check the null cases and saw that there is no "-" char in moduleName variable. Is it possible the reason is my attribute names ? maybe I should give names like RIM-APPID , RIM-IP etc ?

Comment: You said it doesn't go into the for loop. Which For loop are you talking about, the first one or the second one?

Comment: second one.. is there any alternative way to get custom parameters instead of my code ?

Comment: Does it go into `cmg != null` block? If no, then your problem is not getting custom parameters but getting the correct code module group. If it does go into that if condition, and you are not getting the parameters, then it is possible that the app was installed using Desktop Manager or javaloader.

Comment: it goes into that if condition.. My app is downloaded from my jsp. I mean I generate a dynamic jad file. How can I prevent my app to be installed using Desktop manager or javaloader as you mentioned ?