# How to read browser data from app

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I have a blackberry application which can be downloaded from a jsp page that I created. I need to save some data when the user is downloaded my application, and read the saved data from the app when it is opened.

I have tried to put the data to the jad as a custom jad attribute, but I had some problems getting them like this topic : [Null values on reading custom JAD attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005508/null-values-on-reading-custom-jad-attributes)

Is it possible to get data from the outside of the application ?

Comment: What kind of data? Might be easier to let the app download it from your web page if its not generated by the actual device.

Comment: It is just a generated id on the jsp.I generate a unique id for everone who downloads my app. I record everyone and use the generated id in the app. How can I read this id generated in jsp, from my app ?

Comment: no idea ?? I need to solve this problem